# Automatically generate MYSQL table structure from XML data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have an api that returns hundreds of distinct nested properties and values in XML format. I need to store all this information in a mysql database that mirrors the returned XML's structure. Instead of attempting to manually structure the database myself or do it programmatically (which could be equally time-consuming due to the volume and variety of data returned), I want to know if there is some method or toolkit that will generate the appropriate mysql structure.

Comment: Why not just store the xml in a blob column and use xpath queries to use the data?